# ELMAH for ASP.NET MVC 4 using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, elmah

I ran ELMAH sql scripts in test DB(It created ELmah_Error table and 3 stored procedures) and configured ELMAH in MVC application using Nuget.

I modified web.config as specified and I'm able to log exceptions into

```
 http://mysite/elmah.axd
```

But, instead i want to log the exceptions into Sql Server.

I added below class to achieve that

```
public class ElmahHandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext context)
    {
        LogException(e);
    }
    private static void LogException(Exception e)
    {
         // Call to Database and insert the exception info
    } 
}
```

Final step was to:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute ());
}
```

Is it the correct way to use ELMAH to log all exceptions or AM I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you have the database setup, all you need to do is add the following to the `<elmah>` section your web.config to setup the Elmah to log to the SQL Database:

```
 <elmah>
      <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="<DBConnString>"
            applicationName="<YourApp>" 
  </elmah>
```

Replace `<DBConnString>` and `<YourApp>` with appropriate values for your configuration.

Once you have done this you will not need to use your custom ElmahHandleErrorAttribute class.

I am not sure which NuGet package you installed, but I would recommend using the [Elmah.MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) package as it integrates Elmah into MVC exceptionally well by setting up all of the ErrorHandlers and ErrorFilters for you.

Comment: What about an existing elmah configuration? Will elmah create the necessary tables?

Comment: No elamh will not create the existing tables automatically. However, you can download a script to do that for your database type and version from https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/Downloads in the database section.

Comment: I believe it's the connection string name (as defined in the web.config <connectionStrings> section), not the connection string itself, that goes in the connectionStringName="<connection-string-name>" value.